# FormValidation.io, identical validators fire on changing first field

Tags: jquery, validation, formvalidation.io

I am using formvalidation.io, URL: http://formvalidation.io
I am using **identical** validator, in order to validate confirm password.

**Existing Behaviour**: When I start typing in first field, second field with identical validator fires automatically.

**Desired Behaviour**: identical validator must only fire when start typing in second field or has done any interaction with second field till then it is invalid.

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You must have added the identical validator to field setup of both fields

Remove it from the first field i.e. password field.

Just add the identical validator to second field i.e. confirm password.

That should solve your purpose.